# no suitable method found to override RowsInSection xamarin

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

```
   class CallHistoryDataSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        CallHistoryController controller;

        public CallHistoryDataSource (CallHistoryController controller)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        public override int RowSelected(UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            return controller.PhoneNumbers.Count;
        }
        //
        // Returns a table cell for the row indicated by row property of the NSIndexPath
        // This method is called multiple times to populate each row of the table.
        // The method automatically uses cells that have scrolled off the screen or creates new ones as necessary.
        //
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CallHistoryController.callHistoryCellId);

            int row = indexPath.Row;
            cell.TextLabel.Text = controller.PhoneNumbers [row];
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

> `Helloworld_iOS.CallHistoryController.CallHistoryDataSource.RowSelected(UIKit.UITableView, int)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115)

Hi I'm trying to make a helloworld application with xamarin monotouch and I'm taking this error.Can anybody help me about this?

Thank you

Comment: is your class inheriting from UITableViewSource?

Comment: yes its inheriting from UITableView

Comment: No, I asked if it is inheriting from **UITableViewSource**.  That is the base class with the RowSelected method.

Comment: class CallHistoryDataSource : UITableViewSource

Comment: I edited the code you can see

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that you're using the Unified API.

In which case use this (`nint` instead of `int`):

```
public override nint RowSelected(UITableView tableView, nint section)
```

Comment: Nice one, it built :)

Comment: what is the reason behind changing it from int to nint